# Start bash script from specific line ,when i run it for the second time

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Is there anything that i can use to make my bash script start's from specific line when i run it for the second time.

```
    #!/bin/bash
#installed jq by using sudo apt-get install jq
# return indices and os,process
a=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/node01/stats/os,process?pretty=1')

#return just jvm
b=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/node01/stats/jvm?pretty=1')
c=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/node01/stats/indices?pretty=1')

d=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/node01/stats/thread_pool?pretty=1')

e=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/stats?pretty=1')

f=$(curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=uptime')
uptime=$(echo $f | cut -d' ' -f 2)
echo $uptime
echo $e >"parameters4.json"

echo $d > "parameters3.json"


echo $c > "parameters2.json"

echo $b

#uptime=$(cat servrtime.txt | grep  uptime)

host=$(hostname -I)
echo $host
```

when i run it for the second time it has to start fom line  **host=$(hostname -I)** , is there anything to do this??

Comment: Can you write a file somewhere to recognize the second run? If not, is the script run interactively from a bash shell?

Comment: @Florian Weimer Writing file to recognize seems bit complex,yes my script runs interactively

Comment: Perhaps modify your script to accept a CLI argument which you pass in the first time you run the script. Then conditionally run the initial code only when CLI arg is provided. The second time you run the script omit the CLI arg.

Comment: @RobC , i dont have an option to run my script manually, i am running script by using cron.

Comment: In which case writing a file to act as a flag upon script completion, as @RCP alludes to in his comment, and conditionally running the initial code based on it's absence seems plausible.

Comment: You can also set an environment variable while running for first time and check for the variable on second time. I would use functions to group the task(lines) for first and second run. :)  . jumping to a line is not a good solution for shell scripts

Comment: @zappy I think setting env variable will not work if the script is executed from cron. You'd have to store it somewhere and make sure it's loaded when cron runs the script again, which is an overkill IMO.

RCP: writing a file to recognize if the script was already executed is definitely not complex. And run script interactively means that you run it manually from command line and can interact with it (i.e. NOT when you run it via cron)

Comment: @zappy ,that i know but i don't want to run the above commands again and again, i have to perform some other operation on the data i am fetching above

Comment: @JiriValenta , It would be  helpful if you can explain why you think setting env  is not possible with cron job. I have 3 cron jobs in my PC which set and gets environment variable.

Comment: @JiriValenta Sorry for the misunderstanding, my script is not running interactively  i have to run it using cron. If i write a file to recognize that the script was already executed,how the script will start from specific line when i  run it for the next time please elaborate it.

Comment: @RCP you simply surround the one-time code in an `if` condition, so that it will be executed only when the file does not exist. At the end of the execution, you will create the file so that the code will not be executed again the next time. I have posted an answer here, please check

Comment: @zappy I am not saying it does not work, but it seems just over-complicated. You need to make sure that the env variable will persist for new shell sessions, system reboot, etc.. And if you want to get rid of it later, you have to unset it from whereever you are setting it (.bashrc or similar). IMO it is much easier to use an empty file for this purpose, you can create/remove it more easily than messing with env variables. At least that 's my feeling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would not overcomplicate it and touch a file somewhere on the filesystem after the one-time commands are executed.

```
if [[ ! -f /some/file ]]; then
  # your commands that should be executed only once
  touch /some/file
fi

# the rest of the script
```

Make sure you touch the file somewhere where it will not get deleted accidentally.

Comment: @RCP, don't forget to clear that semaphore file to make room for the next run, if there will be one. And click the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to achieve this is by parsing the file from the command you know you want to run using awk or sed.

Say you want to run every command after this line `echo $uptime`

**awk method**:

```
awk '/\$uptime/{y=1;next}y' filename.sh | bash
```

**sed method**:

```
sed '1,/\$uptime/d' filename.sh | bash
```

These will start running all the lines after the mentioned string found.

Note: This will exclude the line which contains the search string, so you can pass the search string from n-1 line if you want to run all lines from nth line.